# Ranking position in solr

Tags: solr

I wonder there is a proper way to fulfill this requirement.
A book has several keyphrases. Each keyphrase consists from one word to 3 words. The author could either buy keyphrase position or don't buy position. Note: each author could buy more than 1 keyphrase. The keyphrase search must be exact and case sensitive.

For example: Book A, keyphrases: agile, web, development
             Book B, keyphrases: css, html, web

Let's say Author of Book A buys search result position 1 with keyphrase "web", so his book should be in the first position. His book should be listed before the Book B.

Anyone has any suggestions on how to implement this in solr?

Chamnap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Query Elevation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent) for that.

Comment: Can the elevated query results xml file be updated easily? It seems the file needs to be updated manually. Moreover, it is not so easy to update the position (let's say from no. 1 to no. 3).

Comment: This features needs to be updated frequently, so i need to update frequently. It's a hard work, and i need to restart solr service as well. that's a big deal.

Comment: If you read link carefull you'll find that restarting is not necessary: If the file exists in the /conf/ directory it will be loaded once at start-up. If it exists in the data directory, it will be reloaded for each IndexReader.

Comment: I sent this command: curl http://localhost:8081/solr/update -F stream.body=' <commit />', but it doesn't reload.

It doesn't reload automatically after every commit or optimize unless I add new document then i commit.